# Inserting multiple CMS blocks into a product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, category-products, cms-block, ee-1.14

My objective is to allow CMS blocks to be added to a category's product collection at various places via the visual merchandiser.

I created a custom table which is similar to `catalog_category_product` except referencing categories and blocks with a relevance/position field, and have created some dummy data with a position that might look like this:

```
1: Product 1, 2: Product 2, 3: Block 1, 4: Product 3, 5: Block 2
```

I.e. three products and two blocks forming five entities.

I am interested to know whether I can swap the product collection that categories use by default out for a custom `Varien_Data_Collection` (`_Db`?) containing both *products and CMS blocks together*. If this is possible, I could then hopefully pass the Frankenstein collection into the "toolbar" pager and have it correctly perform pagination as per normal for the category pages.

**Question:** Is it possible to have a collection containing multiple entity types?

The reason I'm looking at doing this is that the pagination won't really work correctly unless I pass it a final entity collection to paginate. E.g. If my first page had 5 products and 3 blocks and I set the page size to 5 to prevent 8 products from loading then the next page would then load 5 products, but it may actually need to load 8 products if no static blocks exist in the page.

---

I'm having a surprising amount of luck by creating "fake products" in the collection with an observer like so:

```
/** @var Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block_Collection $blockCollection */
foreach ($blockCollection as $block) { /** @var Mage_Cms_Model_Block $block */
    $frankensteinProduct = $productCollection
        ->getNewEmptyItem()
        ->addData($block->getData())
        ->setData('product_or_block', 'block')
        ->setData('entity_id', 'block_' . $block->getId());

    $productCollection->addItem($frankensteinProduct);
}
```

Is this the right approach to be taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question I faced a similar issue a while back when requirement was to be able to add advert panels to show up between the product list.

I did not even try to do a multiple type collection like what you're doing because I assumed it would be hard to implement and the product list highly depends on the fact that objects are products.

What I ended up doing was to **create my own product type that I would use to deal with to create my advert panels.**

Apart from image, name and text I didn't need much so that was enough in my case. I made it behaves like CMS block basically.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I think that's the route I'm heading down too, as the product collection [doesn't allow multiple class types to be added](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php#L260-L266) so I'll need to make it look like a product. The alternative I guess is to create a collection of a new model which could be a placeholder for either a block or a product, but that would be much riskier in terms of the catalog/product associations and type hinting...

Comment: Question though - did you literally create new products in the database for your advert panels? Or were they created in a similar way to my example via an observer?

Comment: @RobbieAverill I first created a new product type via module. Then manually created the advert panels I needed from the backend. But I guess going the observer way could do it too

Comment: So you ended up with custom product database records? Thanks, just curious. That approach was suggested by a colleague but I didn't like the sound of it

Comment: @RobbieAverill yeah I did. I didn't deal directly with the database just created my products in the backend ;)